# checking for two strings converted to lower() not working as intended

Tags: python, input

I have two strings, string0 and string1. I want to check if an input contains these strings in lowercase. However it just checks for one of them.

```
import sys

string0 = "Weather"
string1 = "Like"
userInput = input("say whatever")

if string0.lower() and string1.lower() in userInput:
    print("it is quite nice")
```

Here it'll just check for string1. I don't understand why, any ideas? I'm using python 3

Comment: Because you misuse the `and` operator here. The left hand side will always be `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check each string separately, try this:

```
if string0.lower() in userInput and string1.lower() in userInput:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the conditions individually. The first part will just evaluate to `True`. Every string except for the empty string `''` evaluates to `True`

```
if string0.lower() in userInput and string1.lower() in userInput:
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `or` to check either string, plus, your condition isn't quite right.

```
if string0.lower() in userInput or string1.lower() in userInput:
```

You could also try this

```
if userInput in {string0.lower(), string1.lower()}:
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an and in this case. You will probably need an or.

Comment: No, I want the user to have to type "weather" and "like".

Answer (score -1):

`in` tests if one value is in a list of values. So your logic is backwards, you want to see if the `userInput` is *in* the allowed values:

```
if userInput in [string0.lower(), string1.lower()]:
    print("it is quite nice");
```

Comment: Not in my case, if I do it like you suggested I can't type in "What is the weather like" or anything similar, which is what I want.

Comment: @UlrikKarlsson That is information that should have been included in the question then. Based on what you just said a regular expression would be better suited than the `in` operator.